# Firefox starting before network is up

Tags: 10.04, networking, firefox, startup

We have this machine (ubuntu 10.04) with autologon and firefox in startup sesson aplications.

But some times the firefox starts, and the network is not up (maybe a delay from dhcp server, or some weird problem in networking).

How we change the order of applications of startup session applications? And how we can define to firefox only start after the network is up?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm unsure if all these existed in the 10.04 version of Ubuntu, I'm putting this answer here in case it does and also so it can be used for newer releases. You can use upstart to start a GUI application when a user logs in and have it require that networking is up first.

[Run a GUI application](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-gui-application)

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0
exec /usr/bin/firefox
```

[Run when a user logs in](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-when-a-user-logs-in)

1. This makes use of D-Bus Service Activation.
2. Add "UpstartJob=true" to file "/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.service".
3. Create a job configuration file corresponding to the D-Bus service, say /etc/init/user-login.conf [12]:

   ```
   start on dbus-activation org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit
   exec /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
   ```
4. Ensure that the D-Bus daemon ("dbus-daemon") is started with the --activation=upstart option (see /etc/init/dbus.conf).

Now, when a user logs in, D-Bus will emit the dbus-activation event, specifying the D-Bus service started. You can now create other jobs that `start on user-login`.

[Depend on another service](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-depends-on-another-service)

```
start on (started networking and user-login)
```

By combining these three things in an upstart job, you can start Firefox when a user logs in and the network is started (although you may want to specify which interface is up)